# Find a vector such that its matrix product is positive in every element

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given a matrix $A$ I want to find a vector $\vec{x}$ such that every element of $A\vec{x}$ is strictly positive.  Also, the columns of $A$ do not span the full space, so if I were to just naively pick some $\vec{y}$ with all positive entries, I could not in general find a solution for $A\vec{x} = \vec{y}$.  Is there a method guaranteed to find a feasible point if one exists?  Bonus points if it's a matrix-free method, so I only have to evaluate matrix-vector products, no pseudoinverses or factorizations.  I suspect that this can be set up as a convex program, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Where does $A$ come from? Does it have any particular structure?

Comment: It's a system identification problem.  Really $\vec{x}$ is a matrix $X$, which I right-multiply by another matrix $U$, and then apply the adjoint of the linear operator that constructs a block-Hankel matrix.  If I can find $\vec{x}$ such that $XU$ is positive, then it should work.

Comment: Maybe try solving the linear program $\min_{\alpha,x} \{ \alpha | - \sum_{j=1}^n A_{i,j} x_j \leq \alpha , \  i=1,\cdots, n \}$? If the minimum is $<0$ then you have an answer, otherwise you know no such $x$ exists.

Comment: Equivalently, you want a vector $x$ that has positive dot product with every *row* of the matrix. So it's a question of whether the intersection of open halfspaces determined by the row vectors is nonempty.